# React (Next.js) > Invalid ARIA attribute `ariaHidden` , did you mean `aria-hidden`?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, accessibility

I'm defining a component as:

```
<HiChevronDown
  aria-hidden="true"
  className= "ml-2 h-5 w-5 ..."
/>
```

However, the console warnings state that I am defining it camelCased.

Anything I'm doing obviously wrong here?

Console warning:
[image: invalid ARIA attribute]

Comment: I think this is a bug in react-icons itself. Instead of providing the valid prop 'aria-hidden', it sets 'ariahidden' as prop.

<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5" viewBox="0 0 24 24" ariahidden="true"..........> </svg>

Just copied the code above from the DOM of my NextJS app. Note that a hyphen nor camelCase is used. It should be either aria-hidden (html) or ariaHidden (JSX / TSX).

Comment: Perfect, this was a known issue on their GitHub which was just merged 4 days ago:
https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/pull/630

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem before, and you're not doing anything wrong, this error is just related to the SVG you're using, it's from react-icons/hi and I've noticed that whenever I use an icon from that specific part of the library (`react-icons/hi`) that warning shows up! so that warning won't hurt your app or anything but if you want it to go away just choose another svg from a different part of the library, like `FaChevronDown` or `IoChevronDownOutline`.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your icon is having focusable element.your issue is seems of syntax but it might be because of different taking place.
please refer this [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden#:~:text=The%20aria%2Dhidden%20attribute%20can,children%20from%20the%20accessibility%20tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden#:%7E:text=The%20aria%2Dhidden%20attribute%20can,children%20from%20the%20accessibility%20tree).

Comment: Running into the same issue with non-focusable elements.